# See if nested array of objects contains value | MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection `posts` which has an array of objects `comments`. Within this array of objects, I have another array of objects `likes`.

I am trying to write a query that pulls the most recent 5 comments from a post, and only pulls `true` or `false` for `likes`, based on if the user has liked the comment already.

I have written this so far:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": postId
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": 
        {
            "comments": {
                "$slice": [ "$comments", -5 ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "comments.content": 1,
            "comments.likes": { 
                "$eq":  [ "comments.likes.$.createdBy.username", username ] 
            } 
        }
    }
])
```

But this seems to pull `false` everytime.

Is it possible to do this without having to write a separate query to check if the user has liked?

EDIT: So for the below document:
[image: Test]

With `username = "testusername"`, and `postId = "60fcd335abbe5a73583b69f0"`

I would expect output:

```
[
    {
        "content": "test comment",
        "likes": true
    },
    {
        "content": "another test comment",
        "likes": true
    }
]
```

And with `username = "testusername2"` I would expect output

```
[
    {
        "content": "test comment",
        "likes": true
    },
    {
        "content": "another test comment",
        "likes": false
    }
]
```

#### Answer

Thanks to @ray for your help with this one. [Condensed Code Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sjCjEk1vigK) though please see ray's response for the code split out with explanation.

Comment: would be helpful if you can provide sample data and expected output for everyone here to take a look

Comment: another piece of advice: paste the code/sample data in text instead of image; It would be easier for others to copy and replicate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` to process your arrays layer-by-layer.

1. You can first `$map` comment to project a boolean for if the likes are liked by user1
2. Then you can use `$anyElementTrue` to perform the checking on the projected boolean

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/avSDzdgWwJ5) to show the idea(with some minor modification to your example). You can modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: This is perfect. Haven't used `$map` much before so thank you for this, and for bringing Mongo playground to my life.

Comment: FYI have played around with it a bit to avoid a second projection: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sjCjEk1vigK)

Comment: @bourkison your new code is cleaner. The reason I split the code into 2 stages is for demonstration purpose so you can run the stages separately for better understanding. I would suggest you supplement your new version in your question to help more people out :)